# How do I make a long underscore in Plain TeX?

Tags: rules, plain-tex

I have looked at [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24766/long-underscore-in-latex) as well as [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82266/how-to-create-long-underscore-before-the-text) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/199454/plain-tex-and-underscores) but I cannot figure out how to produce a long underscore in plain TeX, as in the following example.

```
Date _____________________________
```

The closest I have come is the obviously undesirable concatenation which leaves gaps in the rendered output.

```
Date  \_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_
```

Comment: `\vrule height .4pt width 7cm`

Comment: @Manuel, I accept this answer! But can it be placed below the baseline as in [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/24767/24402)?

Comment: Mmm… let's wait for a “pro answer”, the definition in LaTeX has some `\leavevmode\hbox{..}` but then the definition of `\_` is `\leavevmode\vbox{\hrule ..}` so I don't really know enough.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use a negative height and a slightly bigger depth:

```
\vrule height -3pt depth 3.4pt width 7cm
```

Adjust to suit.

[image]

The same idea can be used for “raised rules” (with a negative depth). No rule will appear if depth + height is negative.

If you want a “low rule” that fills up a given space, leaders should be used:

```
\def\lowhrulefill{%
  \leavevmode % be sure to be in horizontal mode
  \leaders\hrule height height -3pt depth 3.4pt\hfill % fill all available space
  \kern0pt % so \par won't remove the rule
}
```

Note that `\leavevmode` is necessary because the command appearing in vertical mode would raise an error because of `\hfill` (and would do nothing good either).

Comment: As noted in comments on the question, is `\leavevmode` best here?

Comment: @JosephWright `\vrule` is a horizontal command, so there's no need. There is for `\hrulefill`, because it does `\leaders\hrule\hfill` and it would give errors in vertical mode.

Comment: Why then the definition of `\_` and `\rule` have `\leavevmode\vbox{\hrule..}` and `\leavemode\hbox{\vrule..}`? In particular, why `\leavevmode` when it's unnecessary and why the definition varies between `\_` with `\vbox{\hrule..}` instead of `\hbox{\vrule..}`? Even, why the `\hbox`/`\vbox`?

Comment: @Manuel `\vbox` and `\hbox` are not horizontal commands, so they don't start a paragraph.

Answer (score 8):

Plain TeX already defines an `\hrulefill` command that does this.  Use it like this:

```
\noindent
Date \hbox to 3cm{\hrulefill}

\bye
```

to produce

[image]

If you would rather have the line drawn a bit lower down, then try this:

```
\noindent
Date \lower.2ex\hbox to 3cm{\hrulefill}

\bye
```

If you were going to use it more than a few times, then you could make a macro:

```
\def\filler#1{\noindent\lower.3ex\hbox to #1{\hrulefill}}

\noindent
Date \filler{3cm}

\bigskip
\noindent
Name: \filler{2in}

\bigskip
\filler{\hsize}

\bye
```

[image]