# How do I add text above a long underscore in Plain Tex?

Tags: pdftex, rules, plain-tex

This is a follow-up to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/210122/how-do-i-make-a-long-underscore-in-plain-tex) and the requirement for Plain TeX is still in place.

I am trying to create the effect of floating a string (date) above the long underscore I create using the first method in the accepted answer.

This is the closest I have come, but obviously the underline does not match up with the underscore.

```
Date \hskip 1 pt \underbar{12-25-2014} \vrule height .4pt width 7cm
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Split the rule into two parts and add the text as a zero width box in the middle; in order to enhance the “floating” character, I slightly raised the box.

```
\def\filltospace#1#2{{%
  \dimen0=#1\relax
  \dimen0=.5\dimen0
  \vrule height -3pt depth 3.4pt width \dimen0
  \raise1pt\hbox to 0pt{\hss#2\hss}%
  \vrule height -3pt depth 3.4pt width \dimen0
}}

Date \filltospace{7cm}{12-25-2014}

\bye
```

[image]

Adding variations about the positioning (not at the center, that is) is easy.

Answer (score 5):

```
foo $\underline{\hbox to 7cm{\hss12-25-2014\hss}}$ bar
\bye
```

[image]

Comment: Was does `\hss` do? I've never heard of this command before.

Comment: inserts infinitely stretchable and shrinkable horizontal glue, like `\hfill` in LaTeX

Comment: `\hss` and `hfill` are both primitives so also defined in latex, `\hfill` only has stretch component, not shrink `\hss` has both.

Comment: I get an error on `\underline`. This may not be available in plain tex.

Comment: do you forgot hte `$...$`? it is a math command

Answer (score 4):

If you need to keep the rule created by `\vrule height -3pt depth 3.4pt width 7cm` then you can write:

```
Date \rlap{12-25-2014}\vrule height -3pt depth 3.4pt width 7cm
```